# split the data into separate file after encountering a column name

Tags: python

```
eno,ename,
101,'sam',
102,'bill',
eno,ename,
103,'jack',
eno,ename,
104,'pam',
```

I have a huge .csv file in which column names reappear after certain number of rows. is there a way in python to split such data into multiple files as soon as it encounter the "repeated column names"?

I would like the above data to be in 3 separate .csv files since the same column names appear 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is to save the headers to a variable, and then when reading the file check if the current row matches the header. If it does, increment a counter that can be used to determine which file to write to.

```
import csv

HEADERS = next(csv.reader(open('data.csv')))
print(HEADERS)
with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    
    file_name_counter = 0
    for row in reader:
        if row == HEADERS:
            file_name_counter += 1
        
        with open(f'data{file_name_counter}.csv', ('w' if row == HEADERS else "a"), newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

NOTE: I believe the `newline=""` argument is necessary on Windows, as otherwise `csv.writer()` will add an extra new line between each entry.

Answer (score 2):

Challenging! Here's my solution. There is likely a more straightforward way to do this though.

```py
with open("./file.csv", "r") as readfile:
    file_number = 0
    current_line_no = 0
    tmpline = None

    for line in readfile:

        # count which file you're on. Also use write mode "W" if the first line. Else append.
        with open(f"./writefile{file_number}.csv", ("w" if current_line_no == 0 else "a")) as writefile:

            # check if the "headers" are appearing and if the current file has more than 1 line.
            #  Not sure if the header check is the best for your use case. Maybe regex is best here.
            if current_line_no != 0 and ("eno" in line and "ename" in line):
                file_number += 1        # increment to next file
                current_line_no = 0     # reset file number
                tmpline = line          # remember the "current line". This needs to be added to next file.
                continue                # continue to next line in readfile
            
            # if there is a templine from previous, add it to this as header.
            if tmpline is not None:
                writefile.write(tmpline)
                tmpline = None 

            # write the line and increment to new line
            writefile.write(line)
            current_line_no += 1
```

I've tried to comment as best as possible. The code basically opens the files one by one as it loops through the lines of the `readfile`. When it reads the contents it checks if the current line is a "header". Here I simply checked if "eno" and "ename" are in the line, but there is probably a better approach for your use case. If the current line is a header, then you need to close the current file and open a new one. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: (You can probably speed this up by creating something like a `current_buffer` variable which dumps to file when a new header is encountered. That way you don't need to keep opening and closing files for every single line.)

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for Python, but there are some questions that just cry out for the power of AWK :)

```
awk '/eno,ename/{x="F"++i ".csv";}{print > x;}' input.csv
```